# Ethereum Token Standard Naming

Tags: tokens, eip, erc

What are the criteria to name an ERC? I'm creating an ERC and I wonder how should I name it. I've been looking everywhere (Medium, Hash node, ETH Stack Exchange) and I haven't been able to find an answer specifying the logic behind the ERC namings.

Comment: What do you mean by ERC? They original meaning was Ethereum Request for Comments, then it was renamed to Ethereum Improvement Proposal (EIP). See here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/44847/difference-and-relationship-if-any-between-erc-and-eip.

Answer (score 0):

You can name your tokens however you please. It would be sensitive to check that a token is not already using the name, but you are limited only by your imagination. As long as you conform to the whichever ERC standard you are implementing, the token should be correctly displayed in UIs.